# Spelling correction by comparison with nearest words

Tags: python, data-mining

I have two lists(List A and List B). `List A` contains list of words whose spellings are incorrect(by few characters) and `List B` contains list of words with all spelling correct.

1. Size of `List A` is less than `List B`
2. Task is to correct spelling of words in `list A` by replacing it with that word from `List B` to which it resembles the most. For eg: if `List A` contains word `[kodarma,belgaum,ysr]` and `List B` contains `[...,Koderma,Belagavi,y.s.r. kadapa,....]`, then these those words of `List A` should be replaced with `List B` words.

What would be the strategy? or only way is to do it manually :(

Comment: How do you define how much does one word *resembles* other word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the module `Levenshtein` to find the similarity factor between the words in the list and provided the `word_similarity_factor` beyond your defined value (for e.g.: 0.50), you can append it to the new list i.e. `list_containing_similar_words`.

The example code is recreated and produced with the required result.

```
from Levenshtein import ratio

list1=['kodarma','belgaum','ysr', 'kedapa']
words=['Koderma','Belagavi','y.s.r', 'kadapa']
word_similarity_factor=0.5

for i in words:
    for j in list1:
        if ratio(i,j)>word_similarity_factor:
            list1[list1.index(j)]=i
```

Comment: @back_bencher, did it work for you?

Comment: word_similarity_factor of 0.8 correctly corrected the spellings. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

We can also calculate Longest Common Subsequence(LCS) and compare every element in List A and List B. "pylcs" module can be used here. Refer this link for documentation - https://github.com/Meteorix/pylcs

```
import pylcs

wrong=['kodarma','belgaum','ysr', 'kedapa']
correct=['Koderma','Belagavi','y.s.r', 'kadapa']
replaced = []

for w in wrong:
    lcs = 0
    s = ""
    for c in correct:
        temp = pylcs.lcs(w, c)
        if temp>lcs:
            lcs = temp
            s = c
    replaced.append(s)
        
print(replaced)
```